# Custom security system doesn't work unless website re-published

Tags: database, security, model-view-controller, permissions

I've written a security module for my MVC intranet that allows administrators to grant permissions to users for certain functions like viewing, editing, deleting etc.  When an intranet user visits a page, the underlying security module checks the SQL database to see if an administrator has given them access to perform the task and, if they have the required permission, they can click a link or whatever.

What baffles me is that the above system doesn't work unless I republish the website after the administrator has granted the permission.  The permission is stored correctly in a permissions table in the database but when the user tries to use the permission it doesn't work.  As far as I can tell my security module is completely standalone and is just a case of reading and writing to a database using static methods like this:

```
if (SecurityManager.HasRole(Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"], "edit")) {  }
```

I'm sure this is just a basic flaw in my understanding but does anyone have any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Sounds like there is an underlying caching issue. I would look into the SQL-client library you are using, the framework you are leveraging, and your implementation of SecurityManager to make sure that you are not unintentionally caching the permissions table.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree it seems that the permissions table is being cached.  I've not done anything to intentionally enable caching and it only affects this one table out of 50 or more in the database.  I'm using Entity Framework.  Is there a way of caching results?  To me it looks like the code is making fresh queries every time but maybe I've enabled a setting that caches this table's data when the website is started.